# How do I solve $\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{π}{3}} \frac{2 \sin x - \sqrt{3}}{\cos \frac{3x}{2}}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Alright, I know, there are easier ways to solve this, like L'hopitals Rule etc.

But I'm not solving it for the answer, just doing it for the fun so I tried using substitution method.

Put $t= x- \dfrac{π}{3}$

$\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{π}{3}} \dfrac{2 \sin x - \sqrt{3}}{\cos \frac{3x}{2}}$

$= \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{2 \sin \left(t+\frac{π}{3} \right) - \sqrt{3}}{\cos \left( \frac{3t}{2} + \frac{π}{2}\right)}$

$= \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3}- \sin t - \sqrt{3} \cos t}{ \sin \frac{3t}{2}}$

Where do I go from here, I'm not able to eliminate the $t$ fully from the Nr and Dr, any help?

**Or any other alternative way that uses only the fact that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \dfrac{ \sin x}{x} = 1$?**

Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

So we already have, after putting $\;t:=x-\frac\pi3\;$ :

$$\dfrac{2 \sin \left(t+\frac{π}{3} \right) - \sqrt{3}}{\cos \left( \frac{3t}{2} + \frac{π}{2}\right)}=\frac{2\left(\sin t\cdot\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2\cos t\right)-\sqrt3}{-\sin\frac{3t}2}=-\frac{\sin t}{\sin\frac{3t}2}-\sqrt3\frac{\cos t -1}{\sin\frac{3t}2}=$$$${}$$

$$=-\frac23\cdot\frac{\frac{3t}2}{\sin\frac{3t}2}\cdot\frac{\sin t}t+\sqrt3\cdot\frac23\cdot\frac{\frac{3t}2}{\sin\frac{3t}2}\cdot\frac{1-\cos t}t\xrightarrow[t\to0]{}-\frac23\cdot1\cdot1+\frac2{\sqrt3}\cdot1\cdot0=-\frac23$$

Comment: @AnkitKumar "Same"...same what? I don't get it? Ah! If you mean "same result", then yes: the correct one, I believe...

Answer (score 3):

$\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{π}{3}} \dfrac{2 \sin x - \sqrt{3}}{\cos \frac{3x}{2}}=2\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{π}{3}} \dfrac{\sin x - \sin \cfrac \pi 3}{\cos \frac{3x}{2}}$

$=4\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{π}{3}} \dfrac{\cos (\cfrac x2+\cfrac \pi 6) \sin (\cfrac x2 - \cfrac \pi 6)}{\sin (\frac \pi 2-\frac {3x}{2})}$

$=4\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{π}{3}} \dfrac{\cos (\cfrac x2+\cfrac \pi 6)  (\cfrac x2 - \cfrac \pi 6)}{\frac \pi 2-\frac {3x}{2}}$

$=-4/3\lim \limits_{x \to \frac{π}{3}} {\cos (\cfrac x2+\cfrac \pi 6)  }$

$=-4/3\cos \pi/3=-2/3$

Comment: There exists no $\;\pi\;$ at the end....

Comment: Thanks. Rush to conclusion, too many errors :(

Comment: Yes...and the final result is wrong, again: $$\frac\pi6+\frac\pi6=\frac\pi3\;$$ and cosinus on this equals $\;\frac12\;$ ...

Comment: That's right. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To end your computation, you can split your expression in two:
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}- \sin t - \sqrt{3} \cos t}{ \sin \frac{3t}{2}} =-\frac{\sin t}{ \sin \frac{3t}{2}}+\sqrt 3\,\frac{1- \cos t}{\sin \frac{3t}{2}} $$
Now it is standard that $\;\lim_{t\to 0}\dfrac{\sin at}{\sin bt}=\dfrac ab$. On the other hand
$$\frac{1-\cos t}{\sin\frac{3t}{2}}=\frac{2\sin^2t}{\sin\frac{3t}{2}}=2\sin t\,\frac{\sin t}{\sin\frac{3t}{2}}.$$
Can you conclude now?

Answer (score 3):

Just to give another approach, let's let $f(x)=2\sin x$ and $g(x)=\cos(3x/2)$ and use the fact(s) that $f'(x)=2\cos x$, $g'(x)=-{3\over2}\sin(3x/2)$, $f(\pi/3)=2\sin(\pi/3)=\sqrt3$, and $g(\pi/3)=\cos(\pi/2)=0$.  From the definition of the derivative, it follows that

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/3}{2\sin x-\sqrt3\over x-\pi/3}=\lim_{\pi/3}{f(x)-f(\pi/3)\over x-\pi/3}=f'(\pi/3)=2\cos(\pi/3)=1$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/3}{\cos(3x/2)\over x-\pi/3}=\lim_{x\to\pi/3}{g(x)-g(\pi/3)\over x-\pi/3 }=g'(\pi/3)=-{3\over2}\sin(\pi/2)=-{3\over2}$$

Thus

$$\lim_{x\to\pi/3}{2\sin x-\sqrt2\over\cos(3x/2)}={\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pi/3}{2\sin x-\sqrt3\over x-\pi/3}\over\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\pi/3}{\cos(3x/2)\over x-\pi/3}}={1\over-{3\over2}}=-{2\over3}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3}- \sin t - \sqrt{3} \cos t}{ \sin \frac{3t}{2}}=\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3}- \sin t - \sqrt{3} \cos t}{ \sin \frac{3t}{2}}\cdot\frac{3t/2}{3t/2}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3} \lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3}- \sin t - \sqrt{3} \cos t}{ t}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
Now, $1-\cos t=2\sin^2(t/2)$
$$\lim\limits_{t \to 0} \dfrac{\sqrt{3}- \sin t - \sqrt{3} \cos t}{t}= \lim\limits_{t \to 0}( \frac{\sqrt{3}(1-\cos t)}{t}-\frac{\sin t}{t})$$
$$=\lim\limits_{t \to 0}( \frac{2\sin^2(t/2)}{t}-\frac{\sin t }{t})$$
$$=\lim\limits_{t \to 0}( \frac{2\sin^2(t/2)}{t^2/4}\frac{t^2/4}{t}-\frac{\sin t}{t})$$
$$=0-1=-1$$
Put $-1$ in (1) to get the final limit, $-2/3$.

Comment: Your last part is...um... so extremely wrong my man

Comment: It seems to be you erased a $\;\sin\frac{3t}2\;$ in the denominator when going from line 1 to line 2. How come? And where does that $\;\frac23\;$ come from?

Comment: @William why's it wrong?

Comment: @DonAntonio $\frac{3t/2}{sin(3t/2)}=1$

Comment: I'm not sure what William exactly mean, but the pass from line 1 to line 2 seems to be basically wrong, as you seem to have taken the limit in part of the expression but **not** in another part. That is strictly forbidden in general, and in particular cases it must be justified. At the end the result is correctL $\;\frac23\cdot(-1)=-\frac23\;$ , but that step is fishy...

Comment: @DonAntonio NO! I haven't done that. I'm taking the limit simultaneously. The first half will tend to zero and second half to -1. I don't know what's wrong with that

Comment: @AnkitKumar That you **first** took the limit and left some $\;t\,'$ s there. Had you *separated* the limits indication you'll have prodcut of limits it'd be correct, indeed. It seems to be just a confusion, yet a little more explanation would yield this as a correct solution, imo.

Comment: @AnkitKumar In the last part, when $t \to 0 \Rightarrow \cos t \to 1$, you have what they call an indeterminate form in the left part. So, how is it just $0$?

Comment: @DonAntonio I've added more detail. Is it better now?

Comment: @William I wrote the argument for that above, in the $sin^2(t/2)$ part

Comment: Oh I see, you have solved it part by part, so yea, you end up with -2/3 in the end if you combine it all.

Comment: @William yes...

Comment: Instead of putting the box around $-1$ you might consider making a statement about putting that result back in above and getting the answer $-2/3$.

Comment: @Clayton It was already clear that I solved separate parts. Wasn't it? Still, done. Thanks!

Comment: It is clear if when reading the solution, but if somebody just glances at it and sees a box, I think it is natural to assume whatever is boxed is the claimed answer.

Comment: @Clayton yeah...